# Extra jQuery in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

In Magento 2, if I use my Javascript debugger's console, I notice there's a global object with a `jQuery` prefix defined.

```
> jQuery111001331609229091555
Object {events: Object}
events: Object
handle: ( e )
toJSON: ()
__proto__: Object
```

What is this object?  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used by [jQuery itself](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/jquery.js#L242). Looks like for internal in library use.

You should not worry about such object.

But you should worry about using global `window` and instance of `window.jQuery`. Prefer way is to use jQuery via RequireJs:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) { ... });
```

or

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Good information, but I didn't ask about using jQuery and RequireJS, or ask where in jQuery's codebase the expando property is defined.   I want to know what this second JS object added to the global namespace is, and why it's there, and why it's only sometimes there.